# Manche guten (Plural) vs. Manche gute (Plural) - gibt es Unterschied?

Tags: adjective-ending

Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen "manche guten" und "manche gute" (Plural)?  Im Grammatikbuch vom Duden steht nichts darüber.

Duden: http://dpaste.com/3NYX512

Answer (score 2):

Die Adjektivendungen müssen den verwendeten Fall, die Zahl und das Geschlecht abbilden.

> *Manche guten Schüler* lösen diese Aufgabe schnell. *(Nominativ plural, bestimmt)*
>
> *(Manch) gute Schüler* lösen diese Aufgabe schnell. *(Nominativ plural, unbestimmt)*

Die Variante *manche gute* leitet nach meinem Sprachgefühl keinen Plural ein. Ich würde immer folgendes erwarten:

> *Manch(e) gute Schülerin* löst diese Aufgabe schnell. *(Nominativ singular weiblich)*

Schau dir bitte die Adjektivdeklination in deinem Grammatikbuch an.

Comment: Danke, ich wusste nicht, dass auch die Form "manch gute" (Plural) möglich ist.

Answer (score 2):

Ich sehe da keinen großen Unterschied. Nach manchen Artikelwörtern wird eben schwach gebeugt: *jener/aller schönen Autos*. Nach manchen Artikelwörtern wird stark gebeugt: *solcher/mehrerer schöner Autos.* Und nach manchen Artikelwörtern ist beides möglich (im Fall von *manche* allerdings nur im Plural): *mancher/irgendwelcher schönen/schöner Autos*.

Wie auch in Ihrem Grammatikbuch ("Im Plural wird sowohl nach Typ I (stark) als auch Typ II (schwach) gebeugt.") werden die beiden Formen entsprechend typischerweise als Alternativen eingeführt. Siehe zum Beispiel auch *Duden*, Das Wörterbuch der sprachlichen Zweifelsfälle, 8. Auflage 2016:

> Nach flektiertem manch- wird das folgende [substantivierte] Adjektiv
>   oder Partizip im Singular schwach dekliniert: *mancher Beamte, manches
>   schöne Kleid, die Ansicht manches bedeutenden Gelehrten, in manchem
>   schwierigen Fall.* **Im Plural wird sowohl stark als auch schwach
>   flektiert: *manche schöne / schönen Aussichten, die Ansicht mancher
>   Gelehrter / Gelehrten, die Geheimnisse mancher schöner / schönen
>   Frauen, für manche ältere / älteren Leute.***

*Ich persönlich* würde im Plural stark beugen: *mancher guter Polizisten*. Dies ist offenbar auch am häufigsten (*Helbig/Buscha*, Deutsche Grammatik, 2001, S. 274: Plural bei *manche* "überwiegend" wie nach Nullartikel).

Comment: "Nach **manchen** Artikelwörtern wird..." - LOL :-)